# Can we pass param to fragment directly use set method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know that we can pass data to `Fragment` using `setArguments` method.
But I also test that if I add a public field in the target fragment and set it from the other fragment, I can also correctly get the field value.
Then why should we use `Bundle` as the communication bridge?
Is there any performance issue that directly setting the fragment field?

```
   public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
       //can we directly set this field rather than using setArguments(Bundle b)?
       public List<String> strings;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the main reasons are that if Android recreate the fragment for various reasons outside of your code, it then calls an empty public constructor of your fragment, so that's why it's recommended to use Bundle. Or at least that's what I've been told.